por que el foco solo funciona con la tecla enter y no con el click del mouse
Es mi primera pregunta en esta plataforma, por favor disculpas si algo no va bien.
Creo que es sencillo el problema pero no logro hacer funcionar el código.
Hay un boton que al oprimirlo con la tecla ENTER o con el click del mouse debería enviar el foco a la caja Entry, pero el código solo lo logra con la tecla ENTER y no así con el click del mouse.
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda, relaciono abajo el código.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

formulario = Tk()

def funcion_foco(event):
    cajon.focus()

cajon = ttk.Entry(formulario, font='Arial 16')
cajon.pack()

boton = ttk.Button(formulario, text='haga ckick con el mouse o presione la tecla enter\n'
                                    'para enviar el foco a la caja')
boton.pack()
boton.bind("<Return>", funcion_foco)
boton.bind("<Button-1>", funcion_foco)


formulario.mainloop()


Esto pasa precisamente porque es un botón. El problema es el orden en el que el evento es procesado, el clic ocasiona que se ejecute primero la callback enlazada con bind(), el problema es que el foco lo vuelve a ganar el botón inmediatamente como parte de la respuesta normal del widget a ese mismo evento (hacer clic en un botón hace que gane el foco).
El clic izquierdo en el bot́ón (y el Enter también) ya está enlazado con la funcionalidad de "pulsar" el mismo. Los botones ya tienen una forma natural de responder ejecutando un código cuando se hace click en ellos, para eso está command.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

formulario = tk.Tk()

cajon = ttk.Entry(formulario, font='Arial 16')
cajon.pack()

boton = ttk.Button(
    formulario,
    text=(
        'haga ckick con el mouse o presione la tecla enter\n'
        'para enviar el foco a la caja'
    ),
    command=cajon.focus
)

boton.pack()
formulario.mainloop()

Pero hay una diferencia, aquí el entry ganará el foco al completar el clic (pulsar y soltar el botón). Si quieres que la callback se ejecute inmediatamente al pulsar puedes usar un Label en vez de un botón:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

formulario = tk.Tk()

def funcion_foco(event=None):
    cajon.focus()

cajon = ttk.Entry(formulario, font='Arial 16')
cajon.pack()

label = ttk.Label(
    formulario,
    text=(
        'haga ckick con el mouse o presione la tecla enter\n'
        'para enviar el foco a la caja'
    ),
)
label.bind("<Return>", funcion_foco)
label.bind("<Button-1>", funcion_foco)
label.pack()

formulario.mainloop()

lo cual evitará el problema de la retencion del foco que ocurría con el botón.
Ten en cuenta que el evento de teclado, el Return, solo será recogido si el widget concreto (el botón o el label en este caso) tiene actualmente el foco. Si quieres que el foco sea ganado por el Entry sin importar donde este el foco en la App puedes usar bind_all() o extender el binding a más widgets.
